Beamer: Adjusting inner theme affects items in table of contents
Objective
My goal is to adjust the CambridgeUS beamer theme to fit the visual requirements of my university.
Therefore I created a new theme called DHBWtheme as a separate file based on the CambridgeUS theme, which is loaded into the preamble of my main beamer .tex-file instead of \usetheme{CambridgeUS}.
I would like to have lists starting with circles instead of squares. But the table of contents does not fully change its typesetting to circles when changing the \useinnertheme{} option.

Problem
When changing the inner theme from rectangles to circles, the subitems in the table of contents do not start with a circle but start with a blank space.
The behaviour I experience comes from changing \useinnertheme{} as stated in the beamer user guide:

default: Items are shown without numbering. Indentation seems broken.
circles: Circles are shown for sections only, not for subsections.
rectangles: Squares for all items as expected.
rounded: Balls for all items as expected.
inmargin: Looks interesting but is out of scope.

Examples
Main beamer.tex
My own theme is loaded in line 12.
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    aspectratio=169,
    ngerman
]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\include{DHBWtheme.tex}

\begin{document}
    \author[Mustermann]{Max Mustermann\inst{1}}
    \title[Abkürzung]{Forschungsfrage oder Projekttitel}
    \subtitle{Projektarbeit 1/2 oder Bachelorarbeit}
    %\logo{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Logo/logo-dhbw}}
    \institute[DHBW]{
        \inst{1}
        Fakultät Wirtschaft\\
        Duale Hochschule Baden-Württemberg\\
        Campus Musterstadt}
    \date[Musterstadt \the\year]{Musterstadt, den \today}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
    \section*{Agenda}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Inhaltsübersicht}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Hinführung}
    
    \section{Theoretische Grundlagen}
    \subsection{Instandhaltungsstrategien}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Machine Learning}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Analyse der Ist-Situation}
    \subsection{Systemlandschaft}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Instandhaltung}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Schlussbetrachtung}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Soll-Konzept}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}

DHBWtheme.tex
You may want to change the inner theme in line 4 to reproduce the issue.
In line 40 the colour of items is set.
\mode<presentation>

%%% Inner Theme
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

%%% Outer Theme
\useoutertheme{infolines}

%%% Color Theme
%% Colours
\definecolor{dhbw-grey}{HTML}{5C6971}
\definecolor{dhbw-red}{HTML}{E2001A}
\definecolor{dhbw-mix}{HTML}{af273a} % 100% red and 60% grey

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=black,bg=dhbw-grey!50}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=dhbw-red,bg=dhbw-grey!25}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=dhbw-red,fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=dhbw-red,bg=gray!5!white}

%% Text
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=dhbw-red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=dhbw-grey}

%% Titles
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=dhbw-grey}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=dhbw-grey!10}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=gray!60!white}

%% Structures
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=dhbw-red,bg=gray!15!white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar primary}{fg=dhbw-red}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar tertiary}{fg=dhbw-red!50!black}
\setbeamercolor*{palette sidebar quaternary}{fg=gray!10!white}

%% Items
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=dhbw-mix}

%% Blocks
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=dhbw-grey,bg=dhbw-grey!25}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=dhbw-grey,bg=dhbw-grey!25}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white,bg=dhbw-grey}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=white,bg=dhbw-grey}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=white,bg=dhbw-mix}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=white,bg=dhbw-mix}

%% Figure Caption
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=dhbw-mix}

%\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
%\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}

\mode
<all>


You can redefine the subsection in toc template to include a circle:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme{circles}

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}
{\leavevmode\leftskip=5ex\llap{%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{subsection number projected}%
    \raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\bullet$}\kern1ex}\inserttocsubsection\par}
   
\begin{document}
 
    \section*{Agenda}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Inhaltsübersicht}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Hinführung}
    
    \section{Theoretische Grundlagen}
    \subsection{Instandhaltungsstrategien}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Machine Learning}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Analyse der Ist-Situation}
    \subsection{Systemlandschaft}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Instandhaltung}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \subsection{Schlussbetrachtung}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Soll-Konzept}
    \begin{frame}
        content
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}



Thank you, this looks fine. Do you know the reason why this can be only achieved with a more workaround-like solution rather than a standard option implemented in the beamer package? I think of sticking with the rectangles option to keep things more simple

@ColinChrist The circle inner theme implements the subsections without a circle. If you don't like the standard result of the circle inner theme, then you need to redefine things

Ok got it. Can you say why the default inner theme does not produce any numbering in the table of contents?

@ColinChrist Presentations usually only have a few sections, numbering them is often not necessary.
